# I try to use image Button in tkinter gui but ERROR

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to use image Button in tkinter gui but ERROR.....
client.py.....

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 59000

class Client:


    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()

        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)
        
        self.gui_done = False
        self.running = True

        gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.gui_loop)
        receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)

        gui_thread.start()
        receive_thread.start()

    def gui_loop(self):
        
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")

        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Message", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        button = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='send_button.png')
        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, image=button, command=self.write)
        self.send_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'NICK':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                self.sock.close()
                break

client = Client(HOST, PORT)
```

error.....

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (gui_loop):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jirap\OneDrive\Desktop\TCP-Chat-Room-Python--master\client.py", line 55, in gui_loop
    button = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='send_button.png')
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

server.py.....

```
import threading
import socket
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 59000

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()

clients = []
users = []


def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

# Function to handle clients'connections


def handle_client(client):
    while True:
        try:
            message = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            user = users[index]
            user2 = str(user)[2:-1]
            broadcast(f'{user2} has left the chat room! \n'.encode('utf-8'))
            users.remove(user)
            break
        
# Main function to receive the clients connection
def receive():
    while True:
        print('Server is running and listening ...')
        
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f'connection with {str(address)}')
        
        client.send('check'.encode('utf-8'))
        
        user = client.recv(1024)
        users.append(user)
        clients.append(client)
        
        user2 = str(user)[2:-1]
        
        # Show to the server
        print(f'User {user} is Connected.')
        
        broadcast(f'{user2} has connected to the chat room \n'.encode('utf-8'))
        
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
        thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    receive()
```

ignore this:
I have added some code and modified several parts of it, but the post cannot be submitted. It is fine if this message appears when asking a new question, but it appears when I am trying to resubmit my edited post. (i try edit this post but stack not let me do this easily )

Comment: You should not run `gui_loop()` in a thread.  Also note that updating tkinter widgets in a thread may cause problem because tkinter is not thread-safe.

Comment: @acw1668 There is some confusion whether tkinter is thread-safe.  That is, if one can
call tkinter functions and methods from any but the main thread.  The
documentation for Python 3 says “yes”.  Comments in the C source code for
tkinter say “its complicated” depending on how tcl is built.  *Many* online
sources say “no”, but that could just be an echo chamber effect. If tcl is built with threading enabled, I've had no problems modifying widgets from a second thread.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test w/out server. Try this. I modified some of them to remove.

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
import tkinter.scrolledtext
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 59000

class Client:


    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

        msg = tkinter.Tk()
        msg.withdraw()
        self.nickname = simpledialog.askstring("Nickname", "Please choose a nickname", parent=msg)        
        self.gui_done = False
        self.running = True
        self.gui_loop()

                  

    def gui_loop(self):
        
        self.win = tkinter.Tk()
        self.win.configure(bg="lightgray")

        self.chat_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Chat", bg="lightgray")
        self.chat_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.chat_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.text_area = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.win)
        self.text_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)
        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')

        self.msg_label = tkinter.Label(self.win, text="Message", bg="lightgray")
        self.msg_label.config(font=("Arial", 12))
        self.msg_label.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.input_area = tkinter.Text(self.win, height=3)
        self.input_area.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        button = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='send_button.png')
        self.send_button = tkinter.Button(self.win, image=button, command=self.write)
        self.send_button.pack(padx=20, pady=5)

        self.gui_done = True

        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.win.mainloop()

    def write(self):
        message = f"{self.nickname}: {self.input_area.get('1.0', 'end')}"
        self.sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
        self.input_area.delete('1.0', 'end')

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
        self.win.destroy()
        self.sock.close()
        exit(0)

    def receive(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'NICK':
                    self.sock.send(self.nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    if self.gui_done:
                        self.text_area.config(state='normal')
                        self.text_area.insert('end', message)
                        self.text_area.yview('end')
                        self.text_area.config(state='disabled')
            except ConnectionAbortedError:
                break
            except:
                print("Error")
                self.sock.close()
                break

client = Client(HOST, PORT)
gui_thread = threading.Thread(None, client.receive)
gui_thread.start()
```

Here is an image:

[image]

Edit: added `self.gui_loop()` in `__init__`

Comment: Are you attempting to connected to irc similar to  Mirc? You may encounter problem.

Comment: Note that the `client.receive()` task is never started.

Comment: @ acw1668. It is not us. It is depend on him. I do not have server side. He is not using irc. He is using client/server

Comment: I tried but it didn't work with my server.py